# Non-void Coroutine Without Return Statement

Tags: visual-c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, c++-coroutine

I am trying to wrap my head around the C++ coroutine feature. I read Kenny's article ([*C++ - Introducing C++/WinRT*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt745094.aspx)) and also tried watching this presentation, [*CppCon 2016: James McNellis “Introduction to C++ Coroutines"*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTqHjjm86Bw). I keep seeing non-void "functions" without some form of return statement. As an example, see the following code sample from Kenny's article. The **PrintFeedAsync** function/coroutine has an **IAsyncAction** return type but there is no return statement in the definition. could someone explain how this works?

```
IAsyncAction PrintFeedAsync()
{
    Uri uri(L"http://kennykerr.ca/feed");
    SyndicationClient client;
    SyndicationFeed feed = co_await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);
    for (SyndicationItem item : feed.Items())
    {
        hstring title = item.Title().Text();
        printf("%ls\n", title.c_str());
    }
}

int main()
{
    initialize();
    PrintFeedAsync().get();
}
```

Comment: The `co_await` call is what causes the function to implicitly return the `IAsyncAction`.

Answer (score 0):

For a function to be a coroutine, its return type has to have certain traits defined that describes how the coroutine will work. C++/WinRT defines those traits for their version of `IAsyncAction` or `IAsyncOperation<TResult>`. Specifically, there are two methods that handle returning from a coroutine: `return_value(...)` or `return_void()`. IAsyncOperation uses the former, and IAsyncAction uses the latter.

Looking at the latest coroutine spec at the time of this answer, we find what happens if there is no co_return statement in the body of a coroutine function:

> If `p.return_void()` is a valid expression, flowing off the end of a coroutine is equivalent to a `co_return` with no operand; otherwise flowing off the end of a coroutine results in undefined behavior.
>
> –["Programming Languages – C++ Extensions for Coroutines" (N4680) § 6.6.3.1/3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4680.pdf#page=15)

Since C++/WinRT defines a [return_void for IAsyncAction's traits](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/dc92f6f56a1f3bd9cac78cee8955fbec79bc7a3c/10.0.16299.0/winrt/base.h#L11758) then the compiler will follow the above rule. At the end where execution flows off the end of the coroutine, the return_void method is used, the same as if you ended the function with `co_return;`. If we look at the definition of return_void, we see it's equivalent to setting the status as Completed and calling the completion handler if there is one.